# What is below a tectonic plate?

Tags: earth, geophysics, earthquake

I know that tectonic plates float on mantle but when two plates move away from each other, is  the mantle below them exposed to the surface?

Comment: Earth Science SE may be better for this question: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is well described by [the Wikipedia article on mid-ocean ridges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-ocean_ridge), and it includes this rather snazzy graphic that nicely answers your question:

[image: Mid-ocean ridge]

As the plates move apart molten rock from the mantle flows up to fill the gap between them.

Comment: And what happens when there is too much gal between the two plates does the whole space is filled with  molten rock..... If so, then does that space filled with molten rock become a new plate